# Azure database export - Premium not supported

Tags: azure, export, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I need to export a database but when I try this action I have problems about 'Configure required settings - Storage (Premium not supported) - Please select bappac'.

Therefore when I try to configure at the 'Storage accounts', no storage accouns is found.

My setting for 'scale for DTU' is Basic.

Comment: Answer posted but, just curious - why would you want to back up your database to premium storage?

Answer (score 2):

Premium storage is only for disks (vhd's), which are page blobs. Azure Database backup creates a `.bacpac` in a directly-accessible block blob. So, you cannot do a database backup to a Premium storage account.